# Count the number of anniversaries between two dates?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

What is the easiest way in Javascript to calculate the number of anniversaries between two dates.

My attempt:

```
module.exports.countAnniversariesBetweenTwoDates = (start_date, end_date, anniversary_date) => {

  if (start_date == end_date) {
    return 0;
  }

  let start_date_year = start_date.getFullYear();
  let end_date_year = end_date.getFullYear();
  let anniversary_year = anniversary_date.getFullYear();
  let start_date_month_and_day = Number(('0' + (start_date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '' + ('0' + start_date.getDate()).slice(-2));
  let end_date_month_and_day = Number(('0' + (end_date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '' + ('0' + end_date.getDate()).slice(-2));
  let anniversary_date_month_and_day = Number(('0' + (anniversary_date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '' + ('0' + anniversary_date.getDate()).slice(-2));

  let anniversary_count = 0;

  // special case for start year
  if (start_date_month_and_day < anniversary_date_month_and_day) {
    anniversary_count++;
  }

  let temp_start_date_year = start_date_year + 1;
  while(temp_start_date_year < end_date_year) {
    anniversary_count++;
    temp_start_date_year++;
  }

  // special case for end year
  if (end_date_month_and_day > anniversary_date_month_and_day) {
    anniversary_count++;
  }
  return anniversary_count;
}
```

Comment: Why not just convert both dates to milliseconds and get the number of whole years between them?

Comment: Why do I feel like there's a one line solution to this haha?

Comment: @MattMorgan That could be imprecise, as you don't get leap years into account by that method. If a couple of hours don't make much a difference, it's peachy. (Also, not both dates - a sufficient condition would be the number of whole years between maximum of start date and anniversary of that year, and end date.)

Comment: Great point @Amadan, though I think it wouldn't be hard to figure out how many if any leap days are in a date range.

Comment: Subtract the years, then add/subtract 1 based on where the anniversary date falls in the range. Something like `end_year - start_year + ( start_day_of_year < anniv_day_of_year ? -1 : 0) + (end_day_of_year <= anniv_day_of_year ? 1 : 0)`

Comment: @MattMorgan [Are you sure?](https://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time) :) Whatever support for datetimes come in whatever API is a godsend. :P

Comment: the solution isnt making use of the anniversary date tho.. or am i confused!?!

Comment: i think @xdhmoore 's solution looks correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one that accounts for leap years:

```js
function validDate(year, month, day) {
  var testDate = new Date(year, month, day);
  return testDate.getFullYear() === year && testDate.getMonth() === month && testDate.getDate() === day;
}

function countAnniversaries(begin, end, anniversary) {
  var countDate = new Date(anniversary.getTime());
  var anniversaries = 0;
  var countYear = begin.getFullYear();
  var anniversaryMonth = anniversary.getMonth();
  var anniversaryDay = anniversary.getDate();
  countDate.setFullYear(countYear);
  while (countDate.getTime() <= end.getTime()) {
    if (validDate(countYear, anniversaryMonth, anniversaryDay) && countDate.getTime() >= begin.getTime()) {
      anniversaries++;
    }
    countYear++;
    countDate.setFullYear(countYear);  
    countDate.setMonth(anniversaryMonth);
    countDate.setDate(anniversaryDay);
  }
  return anniversaries;
}

console.log(countAnniversaries(new Date('Feb 1, 2012'), new Date('Feb 4, 2026'), new Date('Feb 2, 2012')))
console.log(countAnniversaries(new Date('Feb 1, 2012'), new Date('Feb 4, 2026'), new Date('Feb 29, 2012')))
```

Comment: is this the anniversary?  `var countDate = new Date(begin.getTime());`

Comment: It's the date that's potentially an anniversary-- it's set and then checked whether it's before the end date

Comment: but i need to know how many times a certain day/month (anniversary) occurs in a date range. ie. need to pass in 3 parameters to the function `start_date, end_date and anniversary_date`

Comment: edited... `countAnniversaries` now takes an anniversary Date (ignoring the year)

Comment: Im a little confused, why does your second log statement return 3? @Steve

Comment: If you're asking why is it `3` instead of `14`, it's because it's only counting February 29 on leap years... if you're asking why is it `3` instead of `4`, it's because anniversary is open to interpretation... I've edited the answer to count the start year

Answer (score 1):

If you use moment.js you can just get the difference between two dates as years, the use Math.floor() to round down to the nearest full number of years:

```
yearDiff = Math.floor(moment(new Date(endDate)).diff(new Date(startDate),'years'));
```

Edit:  The code above can be simplified a bit more:

```
yearDiff = moment(endDate).diff(startDate,'years');
```

You may have to write some additional code to handle time periods of less than a year, or some other special cases.

You could of course loop through the dates similar to how you do it:

```
var startDate = "03/08/2019";
var endDate = "01/01/2022";
var anniversary = "03/07/2015";
var anniversaryCount = 0;

var counterMoment = moment(startDate);
while (counterMoment.isSameOrBefore(endDate)) {
    var anniversaryThisYear = moment(anniversary).year(counterMoment.year());
    if (counterMoment.isSame(anniversaryThisYear)) {
        anniversaryCount++;
    }
    counterMoment.add(1,'day');
}
alert("Number of anniversaries: "+anniversaryCount);
```

It all depends on what the end result is and how you plan to use the value.

Comment: the solution isnt making use of the anniversary date tho.. or am i confused!?!

Comment: As long as your time period is more than a year, it should be pretty accurate, but there will of course be some special cases when it will not give you the correct result. I updated my answer with code that will loop through the dates similar to what you are doing.